# Structures repeating entered data in C

Tags: c, xcode, macos, osx-elcapitan

I am working on a project for a "C" programming language class. I have an issue that I have been unable to find a remedy to. The issue lies within my structure I am using. It takes whatever data I enter and repeats it 6 times. My code is

For the structure:

```
    struct authstruct
    {
        char userName[MAXCHAR];
        char userPin[MAXCHAR];
    };
```

Line that is receiving input

```
    struct authstruct usr;
    printf("Please enter your username\n");
    scanf("%s",usr.userName);
    while (fscanf(fident, "%s%s", auth.userName, auth.userPin) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%s", usr.userName);
    };
```

Note, I have it set to print the code that it is recieveing for testing purposes. For example if you entered

```
test
```

it would kick out

```
testtesttesttesttesttest
```

The entire code (ignoring non-related functions and without the above  edit) is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Defining of constants */
#define MAXCHAR 10
#define MAXATTEMPTS 3
#define SIZE 10

/* Prototypes */
int AuthFunc(void);

/* Prototype of structure for Authentication Function */
 struct authstruct
{    
    char userName[MAXCHAR];
    char userPin[MAXCHAR];
};

int main(VOID)
{
    int login;
    login = AuthFunc();
    if (login == -1)
    {
        printf("namepass.txt could not be found\nPlease check for file and try again\n");
    }
    else if (login == 1)
    {
        printf("You have tried too many times to login\nPlease restart and try again\n");
    }
    else if (login == 0)
    {
        printf("Success!");
    }
    return 0;
}

/* This function authenticates the user */
int AuthFunc(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fident;
    fident=fopen("namepass.txt", "r");
    if (fident==NULL)
    {
        return -2;
    }

    printf("Hello! Please follow my instructions\n");
    struct  authstruct auth;
    for (i=0; i < MAXATTEMPTS; i++)
    {
        struct authstruct usr;
        printf("Please enter your username\n");
        scanf("%s",usr.userName);
        while (fscanf(fident, "%s%s", auth.userName, auth.userPin) != EOF)
        {
            if ((strcmp(usr.userName, auth.userPin)) == 0)
            {
                printf ("Please enter your password.\n");
                scanf ("%s",usr.userPin);
                if ((strcmp(usr.userPin, auth.userPin)) == 0)
                {
                    fclose(fident);
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("Incorrect username/password.\n");
    }    
    fclose(fident);
    return 1;
}
```

To run this you will need to create a new .txt file named namepass.txt with your selected username / password laid out in a line like the following example

```
test    12345
test2    23456
```

I apologize for the long post, was just trying to be as descriptive as possible. This was complied and run in Xcode 7.3 on a Mac running OSX 10.11.4. If this issue doesn't occur on your machine, please let me know and I'll start digging in my compilers settings.
Thank You

Comment: At least you're comparing username to pin the first time in the loop...

Comment: ...and you never rewind your file between attempts.

Comment: `if ((strcmp(usr.userName, auth.userPin)) == 0)` --> `if ((strcmp(usr.userName, auth.userName)) == 0)`

Comment: Thank you @SamiKuhmonen, BLUEPIXY, and WhozCraig. When I did the fixes you all recommended I was able to fix this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while (fscanf(fident, "%s%s", auth.userName, auth.userPin) != EOF)` looks wrong. `fscanf` returns an `int` which will be `2` if both readings pass.

Modify it to:

```
while (fscanf(fident, "%s%s", auth.userName, auth.userPin) == 2)
```

Also as mentioned by [WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig) in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565678/structures-repeating-entered-data-in-c#comment60731233_36565678), you should either rewind your file to beginning or limit the opening and closing of file inside `for` loop in `AuthFunc`.

from `man fscanf`:

> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even
>   zero in the event of an early matching failure.
>
> The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. 
>   EOF is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case
>   the error indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set indicate the error.

Comment: Also: 1) How is `fscanf()` supposed to know when one string ends and another starts?  2) `findent` hasn't been initialized.

Comment: 1) The != EOF was for that I thought
2) I didn't add the initializing of fident to the short code I pasted at the begining, but if you look thorough the large block it is there.

Comment: Thank you very much, this fixed my issue, adding the line `rewind(fident);` just after the `scanf("%s",usr.userName);` line adds the needed rewinding of the file which when paired with the fixes you and @SamiKuhmonen gave to me allowed this code to run perfectly.